# Using Firebase Database Trigger onUpdate

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, google-cloud-functions

I am trying to make a trigger when my `ignore` field in the Firebase database changes.

```
const functions = require('firebase-functions');
const admin = require('firebase-admin')
admin.initializeApp(functions.config().firebase)
// // Create and Deploy Your First Cloud Functions - All runs in the Firebase Server, not in the Browser
// // https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/write-firebase-functions

exports.dbTest = functions.database.ref('/{uid}/ignore')
    .onUpdate((snap, context) => {

        return snap.ref.child('new').set('dddddd')

      });
```

Just to make a simple test, I created an `onUpdate` trigger on the ref `/{uid}/ignore` which points to something shown on the image below. I was expecting this to triggered when I manually change a field (let's say `ignore/endTime` but nothing happened. I am new to this, so I am confused how to use it. Please help.

[image]

**EDIT**

The function gets triggered but nothing happens. The log says `Function execution took 224 ms, finished with status: 'error'` without any helpful log message.

Comment: Did you deploy the code to [Cloud Functions](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/)?

Comment: Yes. I deployed and it actually gets triggered, but it leaves a message `Function execution took 224 ms, finished with status: 'error'` with no helpful message

Comment: Also, I am confused with the documentation. Not sure how to refer the right location in the database to add new data when the function is triggered.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You seem to be misreading the signature. The `onUpdate()` trigger gets called with a [`Change` object](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/functions/functions.Change). From that object you can get the snapshot `before` and `after` the update, and from either of those you can get the reference.

So:

```
exports.dbTest = functions.database.ref('/{uid}/ignore')
    .onUpdate((change, context) => {

        return change.after.ref.child('new').set('dddddd')

      });
```